# html2canvas error while printing PDF

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I am using `html2canvas`, but I am facing a problem: it's not rendering the entire page as a PDF, it returns only half the page. Why is that?

This is my code:

```
function generatepdf() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('pdf'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    width: 500,
                    height:400,
                }]
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("budget.pdf");
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
 function generatepdf() {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('pdf'), {
           onrendered: function(canvas) {
               var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
               var docDefinition = {
                   content: [{
                           image: data,
                            width: 500,
                            height:400,
                       }],
                   pageMargins: [ 50, 20, 20, 10 ]
               };

               pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).print("budget.pdf");
           },                     
           logging: true,
           useCORS:true,           
       });
       }
```

Comment: increase height from 400 and check your ouput